# PHP and SQL syntax issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am having problems with a (should be simple) bit of code. I am getting info from a form and trying to echo out an entry/ies in a database that match the form specifications. I think that my HTML is correct, and my problem lies in the PHP. Here is my code that I need help with:

```
<?php
    $submit = @$_POST['submit'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $hair = $_POST['hair'];
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];

    if ($submit){
        //open database
        $connect = mysql_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx") or die("Couldnt Connect to Server");
        mysql_select_db("xxxx") or die("Couldnt find database"); 

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `gender`='$gender' AND `hair`='$hair' AND `height`='$height' AND `body`='$body'");
        $query_run = mysql_query($query);

        if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
            while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
                $pic = $query_row['picture'];
            };
        };
    };

?>
```

This is a self submitting page `<form action='thispage.php' method='post'>`. Later down the page in the empty space is where I am going to echo $pic.

Is this method correct/the best way to do it? If need be, I will post the code for the entire page. It is only 75 lines right now.

And before I am told that I should be using SQLi, this is more of a proof of concept right now, and more importantly I don't know how to make the changes from SQL to SQLi.

**edit:** Within the form, there are only  options, not text input (if that matters)

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: Secondy, you are calling the query execution twice more than what's required :)

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ Not twice its thrice. :)

Comment: Fifthly, you're not doing anything with `$pic`.

Comment: Sixthly, if anything is wrong, there is no feedback at all, there's just a white page.

Comment: Is the query returning rows? If not I would do something like and run that query in something like phpMyAdmin:

echo "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `gender`='$gender' AND `hair`='$hair' AND `height`='$height' AND `body`='$body'";

Comment: I echo $pic later at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Also, I have made sure the query works in phpMyAdmin

Comment: If this is a *proof of concept* why don't you just pretend that the MySQL extension doesn't exist at all? If you're aware of its current status, why continue using it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it using modern libraries

```
// check that all required POST parameters are present
if (isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['gender'], $_POST['hair'], $_POST['height'],
    $_POST['body'])) {

    // create DB connection
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxx;charset=utf8',
        'xxxx', 'xxxx');

    // set error mode and use real prepared statements if possible
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    // prepare an SQL statement with parameter placeholders
    // I changed the * to just `picture` as that's all you were using in your OP
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT `picture` FROM `table` WHERE `gender` = ? AND `hair` = ? AND `height` = ? AND `body` = ?');

    // execute with the POST parameters
    $stmt->execute(array(
        $_POST['gender'],
        $_POST['hair'],
        $_POST['height'],
        $_POST['body']
    ));

    // load all "picture" results into an array
    $pics = array();
    while ($pic = $stmt->fetchColumn()) {
        $pics[] = $pic;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `gender`='$gender' AND `hair`='$hair' AND `height`='$height' AND `body`='$body'");
  $query_run = mysql_query($query);

  if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

  while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
     $pic = $query_row['picture'];
    };
 };
```

should be

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `gender`='$gender' AND `hair`='$hair' AND `height`='$height' AND `body`='$body'";

  if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

  while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
     $pic = $query_row['picture'];
    };
 };
```

$query = **mysql_query**("SELECT * FROM `table .........

**$query_run = mysql_query($query);**  extra

Comment: I would suggest you outline just exactly what it is you modified/changed.

Comment: Also if you could help them do this using mySQLi, that be great and a +1

Comment: @GoutamPal At a guess, both downvoted answers feature the deprecated and unmaintained MySQL extension.

Comment: @Phil As user uses the mysql so answer is in mysql... But it is not a wrong answer..

Comment: @GoutamPal Hey, I'm just guessing based on the pattern of votes. I'd have to agree though, promoting bad libraries and code is not a good thing.