# Query not inserting string data into table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert some data into a MySQL database using PHP.  The code I have works fine on localhost, but when I try it on my server the reg_user_id, reg_user_access_level and  reg_user_status are inserted while all the other fields are not.

Please help, I've already wasted a day trying to sort this out.

everything up to here is fine

The PHP is:

```
else {
    //sort the data
    $reg_user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reg_user_name']);
    //create a salt for the password before encryption, use the same when retrieving the password!
    $salt = 'mysalt';//not actually this
    //first encryption
    $reg_user_password = sha1($_POST['reg_user_password']);
    //second encryption with salt
    $reg_user_password = sha1($salt.$reg_user_password);
    $reg_user_password = mysql_real_escape_string($reg_user_password);
    /*** strip injection chars from email ***/
    $reg_user_email = preg_replace( '((?:\n|\r|\t|%0A|%0D|%08|%09)+)i','',$_POST['reg_user_email']);
    $reg_user_email = mysql_real_escape_string($reg_user_email);

    //connect to the db
    include '../-useful_scripts/php/mysqli_connect_dsnydesign.php';

    //check the connection
    if($dbc) {

        /*** check for existing username and email ***/
        $query = "SELECT reg_user_name, reg_user_email FROM reg_users WHERE reg_user_name = '{$reg_user_name}' OR reg_user_email = '{$reg_user_email}';";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        if (sizeof($row) > 0) {
            foreach($row as $value) {
                echo $value.'<br>';
            }
            if($row[0] == $reg_user_name) {
                $errors[] = 'Sorry, the username is already in use';
            }
            elseif($row[1] == $reg_user_email) {
                $errors[] = 'This Email address is already subscribed';
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
            /*** create a verification code ***/
            $verification_code = uniqid();
            //set the query
            $query = "INSERT INTO reg_users(reg_user_id, reg_user_name, reg_user_password, reg_user_email, reg_user_access_level, reg_user_status) VALUES (NULL, '$reg_user_name', '$reg_user_password', '$reg_user_email', '1', '$verification_code');";
            //run the query
            if(mysqli_query($dbc, $query)) {
```

just goes on to notify of submission after this.

Comment: is reg_user_id your primary key ? is it set to auto-increment ?

Comment: try removing reg_user_id from the insert query and the corresponding NULL value from the insert query and see if that works. Since reg_user_id is set as primary key and auto-increment, you don't need to specify its value in your insert query.

Comment: @Maximus2012 not the problem when using NULL assigned to it.

Comment: @Prix shouldn't the primary key be unique ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 when the primary key is present on the query and assigned to NULL MySQL will automatically assign it as if it was not present.

Comment: Since you're using `mysqli_`, learn to use its prepared statements instead of shoving raw data into queries. And get rid of `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: No luck, it still only adds the three fields.  I have the database set up as utf-8, would this affect anything?

Comment: @user2417303 Try using `echo mysqli_error($dbc);` after your queries to see if they present any error.

Comment: @Prix I wasn't exactly sure about that. Also the OP might want to remove semicolon from the end of the query statement: '$verification_code');"; should be '$verification_code')";

Comment: @DCoder I thought all added strings had to be escaped

Comment: @Maximus2012 Does not affect it either. user2417303 yes to prevent SQL Injection but instead of using `mysqli_real_escape_string` MySQLi have a way better way of dealing with it.

Comment: @user2417303 also make sure you check the error_log file as it may contain important information related to the problem.

Comment: I already have the mysqli_error($dbc) set up if the query fails.  It's not failing, just not adding all the data.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? what is not adding all the data means ? what fields are not being inserted ? what were u expecting ? does it execute your script all the way ? [See here an example of using prepared statements with MySQLi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938906/php-and-sql-syntax-issue/17939168#17939168)

Comment: @user2417303 also can you post the output of `echo $query;` place it after your 2nd query on the above code.

Comment: take your insert query code and take all other code out of the script (make test file, comment it out etc) and try inserting with text (ie no vars, POST etc) and make sure it's working fine. If it's not then it's something with mysql or your query or link between your query and mysql. If it works fine with just inserting text directly then it's an issue with your script somewhere and not the server, mysql, etc (you need to rule these out, as it was working on localhost but now not on the server, there are hundreds of things that could be different between the two platforms)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you are using the same PHP version number on your server and your localhost. mysql_real_escape_string has been deprecated in the latest version of PHP.

Comment: localhost version is 5.3.5.  On the server its up to date. I have stripped all the mysql_real_escape-string() out and the data has transferred.  Will now start to learn prepared statements.